Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxx' or one of its dependencies
Encountered this infamous DLL issue. Unable to resolve it even after following different steps.
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference
Things I've tried so far:
Added the following in App.config
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.1" newVersion="4.2.0.1" />
  </dependentAssembly>

In packages.config
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" version="4.5.3" targetFramework="net48" developmentDependency="true" />


In .csproj file:
<Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\..\Users\admin\Downloads\packages\packages\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.5.4\lib\net461\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>

Added the above in the loading web project as well. Still getting the same exception.

This question is similar to: Unable to load System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You are referencing a different version than the one installed on your machine.  First try a clean build to get all the intermediate obj files to recompile.  If that doesn't work than remove the changes to the csproj file.  Then from Solution Explorer delete the reference to the library.  Than add the library again which should update the csproj file with the correct version of the library.
